# dictionary = dict( 1="Some_value") doesn't work. But dictionary = { 1 : "Some_Value" } does work

Tags: python, dictionary

I was learning about dictionaries in python and I encountered  a strange case when trying to initialize dictionaries using the built function.

`Dictionary = dict( 1 = "Some_Value")` raises an
*syntax error :  expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?*

But 1 can be used as key while initializing the dictionary using the below method
`Dictionary = { 1 : "Some_Value" }` works just fine.

Comment: That's because in the former expression you're using `dict` class constructor (function) to build a dict, and in latter you're using a dict literal `{}`. Functions (the former case) accept only [valid identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) for keywords (dict keys) -- and `1` is not a valid identifier. Loosely speaking, identifiers start with a letter or underscore, and can contain numbers (but not to start with a number).

Comment: Thanks @randomir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines of Python have the same *semantics* (they're both creating a dictionary), but they are very different from a *syntactic* point of view.

With this bit of code:

```
d = {1: "Some value"}
```

you are using the syntax for dictionary *literals*. Only a few types have literal syntaxes, namely: number types (`14`, `12.3`, `2j`), tuples (`(a, b, c)`), lists (`[d, e]`), strings and bytes (`"string"`, `b"bytes"`), booleans and `None`, sets (`{a, b, c}`), and finally dicts.

In a dictionary literal, Python syntax allows any kind of value (although types that are not *hashable* will raise a `TypeError`). You can put a string, a float or a frozen set.

The other bit of code:

```
d = dict(1="aa")
```

tries to use the `dict` constructor to build the dictionary. That constructor is just a standard function, and that notation must respect the syntax for function calling. This syntax allows only valid *identifiers* as argument names. As an identifier must start with a letter, `1` is not a valid identifier, and you thus cannot build that dictionary using this syntax.

However, you can build the dictionary using the constructor, and then sets the value for that same key:

```
d = dict()
d[1] = "aa"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Your interpreted shows a strange error, this is a correct error for this:

```
>>> d = dict(1="aa")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

> a strange case

It's not strange if you look into how it works underneath:

`dict` is a function and cannot have parameter names that are not valid identifiers.

If you have `def f(a): ...` - you can run it by writing `f(a=1)`, right? Can you do `def f(1)`, where `1` is a parameter name? Nope.

`dict` works just like that - those key=value are parameter_name=value underneath. `dict` takes any number of key=value pairs, with any name you wish... well, any *valid* name. (This is done by using `**kwargs` in parameters, fyi.)

And yes, we're always told those two are "the same", yet this is a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @h4z3